# How to create mockito unit tests in functions that use Mutiny.Session

Tags: mockito, quarkus, reactive, mutiny

After some investigation I continue to pursue a more intuitive way to mock Mutiny.Session and test my functionality.

Here the method I want to test:

```
public class ServiceCrud {

    @Inject
    Mutiny.SessionFactory mutinySessionFactory;

    @Inject
    MicroserviceService service;

    public Uni<Service> get(@NotNull final String identifier) throws ConstraintViolationException, NotFoundException {
        return mutinySessionFactory.withSession(session -> {
            EntityGraph<Service> entityGraph = session.getEntityGraph(Service.class, "exampleEntityGraph");

            return service.get(identifier)
                .onItem().ifNull().failWith(NotFoundException::new)
                .onItem().transformToUni(
                    microservice -> Uni.createFrom()
                        .item(new Service(microservice.getMsId(), microservice.getMsName())));
        });
    }
}
```

The only way I found to test was through the argument captor:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ServiceCrudTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceCrud serviceCrud;

    @Mock
    Mutiny.SessionFactory mutinySessionFactory;

    @Mock
    MicroserviceService service;

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<Function<Session, Uni<Service>>> captor;

    @Mock
    Session session;

    @Mock
    EntityGraph<Service> entityGraph;

    @Test
    void getTest() {
        // data
        String msId = "msid";
        String msName = "name";
        
        Microservice toBeReturned = new Microservice();
        toBeReturned.setMsId(msId);
        toBeReturned.setMsName(msName);
        
        Service expected = new Service();
        expected.setId(msId);
        expected.setName(msName);

        // expectation
        doReturn(Uni.createFrom().item(toBeReturned))
            .when(service).get(anyString());
        doReturn(entityGraph).when(session)
            .getEntityGraph(Mockito.eq(Service.class), Mockito.anyString());

        // action
        serviceCrud.get("");
        
        // capture the function and invoke it
        Mockito.verify(mutinySessionFactory).withSession(captor.capture());
        Function<Session, Uni<Service>> value = captor.getValue();
        Uni<Service> callback = value.apply(session);
        
        UniAssertSubscriber<Service> subscriber = callback
                .subscribe().withSubscriber(UniAssertSubscriber.create());
        subscriber.assertCompleted().assertItem(expected);
    }
}
```

Is it the only way to test? Is this the correct way to test?

Any tips will be appreciated

Comment: I would argue testing reactive code like this does not bring much benefit...

Comment: @geoand can you elaborate? Why does not bring benefit?

Comment: You are mocking out the reactive bits, which are actually where the entire complexity of producing proper code is.

Comment: I agree, I still thought about extracting the content to a separate method and then just testing this method. But I don't like the idea of changing the business code just to make testing easier . . .